# Strange different results when dump two adjacent C arrays on Intel X_86 and ARM architectures

Tags: c, arrays, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm getting two different results when dumping the same two arrays with C, in two different below computer architectures. Can anyone explain me the reason?

1. Architecture One: x86_64 (ordinary 64bit intel PC with fedora 23)
2. Architecture Two: armv7l (raspberry pi with raspbian)

here's sample the code

```
double ytops[7];
double ybots[7];                     

// Assigning values loop
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    frame_grabber(); // some custom function that gives sensor data with two variables: ruler_top_cal_preset, ruler_bottom_cal_preset integer

    ytops[i] = ruler_top_cal_preset;
    ybots[i] = ruler_bottom_cal_preset;

    printf("ytops[%i]: %f \n", i, ytops[i]);
    printf("ybots[%i]: %f \n", i, ybots[i]);
}

printf("---raw-array--- \n");

for(int i = 0; i<8; i++ ){ 
     printf("ytops[%i]: %f \n", i, ytops[i]);
}

printf("--------------- \n");

for(int i = 0; i<8; i++ ){ 
     printf("ybots[%i]: %f \n", i, ybots[i]);
}

printf("-------end----- \n");
```

**Architecture 1(X_86) gives this results:**

```
ytops[0]: 143.000000 
ybots[0]: 211.000000 
ytops[1]: 143.000000 
ybots[1]: 211.000000 
ytops[2]: 143.000000 
ybots[2]: 175.000000 
ytops[3]: 144.000000 
ybots[3]: 175.000000 
ytops[4]: 144.000000 
ybots[4]: 175.000000 
ytops[5]: 144.000000 
ybots[5]: 175.000000 
ytops[6]: 144.000000 
ybots[6]: 172.000000 
ytops[7]: 143.000000 
ybots[7]: 172.000000 
---raw-array--- 
ytops[0]: 143.000000 
ytops[1]: 143.000000 
ytops[2]: 143.000000 
ytops[3]: 144.000000 
ytops[4]: 144.000000 
ytops[5]: 144.000000 
ytops[6]: 144.000000 
ytops[7]: 143.000000 
--------------- 
ybots[0]: 211.000000 
ybots[1]: 211.000000 
ybots[2]: 175.000000 
ybots[3]: 175.000000 
ybots[4]: 175.000000 
ybots[5]: 175.000000 
ybots[6]: 172.000000 
ybots[7]: 172.000000 
-------end-----
```

**Architecture 2 (ARMV7l) gives this:**

```
ytops[0]: 206.000000
ybots[0]: 413.000000
ytops[1]: 206.000000
ybots[1]: 411.000000
ytops[2]: 205.000000
ybots[2]: 427.000000
ytops[3]: 206.000000
ybots[3]: 415.000000
ytops[4]: 205.000000
ybots[4]: 416.000000
ytops[5]: 205.000000
ybots[5]: 421.000000
ytops[6]: 206.000000
ybots[6]: 411.000000
ytops[7]: 206.000000
ybots[7]: 418.000000
---raw-array---
ytops[0]: 418.000000
ytops[1]: 206.000000
ytops[2]: 205.000000
ytops[3]: 206.000000
ytops[4]: 205.000000
ytops[5]: 205.000000
ytops[6]: 206.000000
ytops[7]: 206.000000
---------------
ybots[0]: 413.000000
ybots[1]: 411.000000
ybots[2]: 427.000000
ybots[3]: 415.000000
ybots[4]: 416.000000
ybots[5]: 421.000000
ybots[6]: 411.000000
ybots[7]: 418.000000
-------end-----
```

Of course the numerical values are different when comparing the both result sets due to the sensor data which were at that movement. Its acceptable.

On architecture one, everything is as assigned by the value assigned loop. Its correct. However look at the architecture two's result set's  'ytops[0]' value in "value assigning loop" and the same value of "raw-array" print.

`ytops[0]` is getting the value of `ybots[7]`

How this is possible? What is this phenomenon is called? how to avoid this?

Comment: enable `-Wall` and read the warnings at compile time

Comment: You tagged this as `C++`, but if you had actually used `C++`, [the error becomes obvious](http://ideone.com/qEoA0T)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah. I removed the tags and thanks for the info.

Comment: Explain the down vote please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your for are wrong.

Using [c](/questions/tagged/c) array indexes start from `0` to `length_of_array-1`

So, using

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
```

you are accessing the array out of bounds due to last `i` value that is `7`: your array start from `ytops[0]` to `ytops[6]`. This is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

You must use

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
```

Best if you do, for example using `ytops` array

```
for(size_t i=0;i<sizeof(ytops)/sizeof(ytops[0]);i++)
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why its working when run on intel PC?

Comment: @inckka Due to memory alignment, I guess. Try to print addresses of both arrays and see if there is more than 1 `double` between last element of first array and first element of the second array.

Comment: @inckka The behavior is undefined, meaning anything can happen.  Asking why it "works" is pointless since "working" is one thing that can happen if the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I totally agree but I think is a good exercise to understand why and how a specific undefined behavior can be deterministic with a specific configuration. It engraves the concept in the memory.

Comment: @LPs: but this undefined behaviour depends on the particular version of the compiler and the computer chip it runs on.  The reason for the difference in behaviour is because the compiler knows `ybots` and `ytops` don't overlap and it is free to reorder memory writes to them, and can also print the values contained from registers before flushing to memory (knowing that the memory region can't be changed by any other instructions).  Oops, the above doesn't apply if you invoke UB, but then the compiler is free to give _any_ result.

Comment: @dave Probably. It can also depends on caches setting on armv7. Many reasons that can be investigated using real platform with correct compiler.